# Is [weak self] required in ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization?

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering, how can I decide, whether `[weak self]` is required in `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization`, to prevent memory leak?

### Without [weak self]

```
ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
    // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
    let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: GADAdSizeBanner)
    self.bannerView = bannerView
    
    bannerView.delegate = self
    
    bannerView.adUnitID = Constants.BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
})
```

### With [weak self]

```
ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { [weak self] status in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    
    // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
    let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: GADAdSizeBanner)
    self.bannerView = bannerView
    
    bannerView.delegate = self
    
    bannerView.adUnitID = Constants.BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
})
```

How I can know, whether `[weak self]` is required, to prevent memory leak?

Comment: If the method is marked as async there must be a reason. So I would use it just to make sure. Nothing to lose if you add it.

Answer (score 0):

According Apple documentation, the method `requestTrackingAuthorization` has an escaping closure parameter:

[image]

An escaping closure is a closure that **can** go out of the scope where it was being used and live any time.
So if you don't know inner realization of a `ATTrackingManager`, you'd better assume the worst. In this case the worst assumption is that `ATTrackingManager` is a class that lives as long as the whole application lives so it can capture `self` and hold it forever causing memory leaks.

And despite in this case (as I checked) there is no memory leak, the general rule will be to use `weak self`, because you can't be sure the realization of an `ATTrackingManager` won't change in next releases.

Answer (score 0):

There absolutely is no retain loop here, and `weak` absolutely is not required in order to prevent a memory leak. `self` has no reference to the `ATTrackingManager`, so there's no loop by having `ATTrackingManager` hold a strong reference to `self`. That is definitely not a reason to use or not use `weak self` here.

The reason to use or not use `weak self` here is based on what you want to happen if whatever `self` refers to is otherwise released. Should GADBannerView be created, or not? If this block should not be run in that case, then using `weak self` enables you to check if `self` is gone. If `self` should never be released before this callback, then use strong `self` to express that.

In this case, you probably don't want this screen to go away until the auth request finishes, so you should not use `weak`.

As a rule, delegate-like closures that are called repeatedly need `weak self` since they generally have a retain loop that cannot be broken. "Callbacks" (i.e. things that are called exactly once) do not, because once the callback is executed, the closure should be released, and any loop will be broken.

But who am I kidding? Few people think very much about the semantics, and just slap `[weak self]` on everything and that rarely is actually a problem, while the reverse can be a problem. Adding `weak` everywhere isn't "careful." It's just sloppy. But it's a sloppiness that works ok in practice. It's just annoying to look at.